# Non-invertible Linear Operators whose Sum is Linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Is there a vector space $V$ and two linear operators on $V$, $S$ and $T$, such that $S$ is injective and not surjective, $T$ is surjective and not injective, but $S+T$ is bijective? Dimension arguments rule out finite dimensional vector spaces, so $V$ would have to be infinite dimensional if such a pair of operators existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this actually works: Let $V\leq \mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ be the subspace of sequences that converge to $0$. Let $S$ be the surjective left shift operator, which sends $(a_1, a_2, a_3,\ldots)\mapsto (a_2, a_3, a_4,\ldots)$, and let $T$ be the difference operator, which maps $(a_1, a_2, a_3,\ldots)\mapsto (a_1-a_2, a_2-a_3, a_3-a_4,\ldots)$. $T$ is injective, since the kernel consists of constant sequences that converge to $0$, i.e., just the zero sequence. Then, $S+T$ is the identity operator and thus bijective.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $V\subset \mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ of all sequences of finite length. Let
$$
S(a_1,a_2\cdots)=(0,a_1,a_2\cdots),  T(a_1,a_2\cdots)=(a_2,a_3,a_4\cdots)
$$
Then we have
$$
(S+T)(a_1,a_2\cdots)=(a_2,a_1+a_3, a_2+a_4\cdots)
$$
which is an isomorphism. It is clearly surjective. To show it is injective we would need
$$
a_2=0, a_1=-a_3, a_4=0, a_{n}=-a_{n+2},\forall n\ge 1
$$ 
But since the sequence is of finite length this cannot hold. So it must be an isomorphism.

Comment: @mfl: Thanks for pointing out. Shall fix that.

Comment: Yes, your suggestion does not work. Hopefully fixed now.

Comment: How come? I am still worried a little with $S+T$, let me check.

Comment: I think $T$ is surjective. But I have to say I fixed this partly by learning from your answer.

Comment: @mfl: You mean $(a_1,0\cdots )$ is not in the range of $T$? But this is coming from $(0,a_1\cdots )$.

Comment: Ah, I tried this for the vector space of possible infinite sequences, and it didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: Darn, this doesn't seem to work, since $S+T$ cannot give $(1, 0, 0\ldots)$, since that would force $a_2=1, a_4=-1, a_6=1$, etc., which does not have cofinitely many $0$'s.

Comment: @Nishant: Oops! Let me try to fix it.